# ngInclude directive in template twig symfony 2 not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, symfony

I bought an html/angular js  template and i try to integrated it in symfony 2.
The directive ng-include seems to be not working.

```
{# src/Neobe/AccueilBundle/Resources/views/layout.html.twig #}

{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}
{% block title %}
Welcome 
{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
<!-- Wrapper-->
<div id="wrapper">

<!-- Navigation -->
<div ng-include="'views/common/navigation.html'"></div>

<!-- Page wraper -->
<!-- ng-class with current state name give you the ability to extended customization urview -->
<div id="page-wrapper" class="gray-bg {[{$state.current.name}]}">

 <!-- Page wrapper -->
  <div ng-include="'views/common/topnavbar.html'"></div>

    <!-- Main view  -->
    <div ui-view></div>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <div ng-include="'views/common/footer.html'"></div>

</div>
</div>
 <!-- End page wrapper-->


{% endblock %}
```

The layout which is included templates, layout.html.twig , is located in my public folder of my bunlde Accueil :
AccueilBundle/Resources/views/Accueil/layout.html.twig

The navigation.html template is located in my public folder of my bunlde Accueil :
AccueilBundle/Resources/views/Accueil/views/common/navigation.html

Can you tell me what's  wrong  ?

i have no error in the browser but nothing is included.

Thank u for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK the syntax for the `ngInclude` directive is

```
<div ng-include src="path_to_your_html"></div>
```

or

```
<ng-include src="path_to_your_html"></ng-include>
```

Comment: i have seen this answer a lot of time i tried all syntaxes but nothing changes and the thing is that in the original folder of the template that i bought they are using this synthaxe : <div ng-include="path_to_my_html"></div> and it works well. It is only in symfony that the problem exist.

Comment: Hmm, maybe your paths are off. Have you tried defining the path in your JS as a scoped variable, say `$scope.pathToHtml = '/path/to/partial.html';` and then use that scoped var in your HTML template?

Comment: No do not try this, i have downloaded chrome lauch batarang, batarang do not shows me any scope ?? I am going to try what you say.

Comment: unfortunatly it does not help its like no angular is present in my code i dont understand.

Comment: I put an alert in my js controller file, no alert, seems like it is not called

Comment: Good news my js is know recognized and i have this error :  Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module inspinia due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $stateProvider is that mean that the module $stateProvider is not included properly?

Comment: Well, check if you listed it in the dependencies array of your "inspinia" module.

Comment: It works now the problem a mistake, i wrote     <script src="{{ asset_url }}"  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /></script> copy and paste error, javascript was lost.

Answer (score 0):

Angular (on client side) can't access/find any files that are outside your web directory.

So I think you have to move/copy/asset-install them to /web/.

Comment: Thank u for your answer, but i already done this, i copy the views directory to the web folder and public's folders like js css etc.. too.But it still does'nt work.

Comment: If you open the developer tools in your browser (shortcut is mostly F12) you should see some errors in the console and/or the requests (with paths) made by angular in the networking section.

Comment: Thats the problem i have no error in the console i've just intalled AngScope plugin for mozilla hope it is going to show me something.